# Implement WSP of a Web Service but dont appear external content type

Tags: 2010, solution-package, solution-deployment

I'm trying to install a development I did.

Works fine on development environment but on production environment not.

I install the same package that works fine on development on production.
Install fine.
Implements good.
But when I try to create the new external list with the external content type don't appear. :(

On Designer, don't appear too...
What happened? I need help!

I use Sharepoint 2010

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Try reactivating solutions on web applications where you are trying to create external content type.
Check Application Services in Central Administration if there are configured same as in DEV and PROD environment.